# Which APP should I use if I want to draw a workflow with mathematical expressions on Mac?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, graphics

I want to find a graphic application that can draw basic workflows with mathematical expressions. For example, I want to draw something like the following figure from "Implementation and Optimization of Differentiable Neural Computers" by Carol Hsin.
[image]

Comment: See [this Meta answer](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2181/88313) for important guidelines that should be followed when asking for a hardware/software recommendation. It will help everyone by preventing unnecessary answers for items that don't fit your request and could help prevent down votes and closure.

Comment: `https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/LaTeX_Graphics_using_TikZ:_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_3)—Creating_Flowcharts` code since the link would break at the dash. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168314/how-to-use-latex-commands-to-draw-a-flowchart

Comment: Hi, I've changed the title. Does this help clarify my request? I find LaTeX is too complex and it is hard to find a friendly document to start with. Could you please offer a simpler tool? or a more friendly document and application for LaTeX that can help me draw the above picture? Thanks @ankii

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keynote on the mac can do both. It has standard shapes and the ability to draw lines connected to those shapes.  It's a simple way to draw a flowchart. If also supports mathematical expression thru latex. There is an option to insert an equation and you can define anything you like by using latex.

[Here is a link](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php?lang=en-en) to help you with Latex. On this link, you can see what the latex command is for most any symbols you can imagine. I use this page to help me find the correct latex command to put in Keynote.

I have included a very simple and crude flowchart I made in about 5 minutes using Keynote.  The math equations are bogus as I was just trying to show the capabilities of Latex.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Omnigraffle](https://www.omnigroup.com/omnigraffle/) can [make flow charts](https://support.omnigroup.com/create-a-flowchart/) very easily. It's very good at linking lines to boxes, so that you can reposition the boxes and retain the linking.

Comment: Hi, I used Omnigraffle for sometimes, it does not support mathematical expressions. And expression copy-pasted into could be very blurry somehow. I want something that supports both flow charts and mathematical expressions

Answer (score -1):

- Photoshop and InDesign could do some of that. I am not sure of fonts being mathematical, so see if you can find 3rd-party fonts for the same. Adobe Illustrator is used for vector graphics extensively.

  > The industry-standard vector graphics software  is used by millions of designers and artists to create everything from gorgeous web and mobile graphics to logos, icons, ..

  https://www.adobe.com/products/illustrator.html
- [Autodesk SketchBook](http://help.autodesk.com/view/SKETPRO/ENU/?guid=SKETPRO_Help_sb_tools_how_to_use_shape_tools_html) can also help draw basic shapes rectangles, lines.
- Same for https://draw.io
- I'd still add LaTeX as an option. You shouldn't be scared of it. 
  `https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/LaTeX_Graphics_using_TikZ:_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_3)—Creating_Flowcharts` gives an introduction. Use templates given on that site to start drawing. Use https://tex.stackexchange.com/ for reference or asking doubts.

  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168314/how-to-use-latex-commands-to-draw-a-flowchart gives you a working solution too.

Comment: See if you can make that em dash in the URL work, and replace code with link.

Comment: Photoshop is a terrible idea: it's a bitmap editor for photos, not a drawing package for vector objects. Illustrator would be the Adobe tool best suited.

Comment: I somehow completely missed illustrator!

Comment: Also, Ps exports png right ? and vectors can be drawn using Pen tool I guess. How come it can't draw vector objects ? Or do you mean that it is tough to draw using it ?

Comment: Well, OK: it can draw paths and text, but it's primarily a bitmap editor and you have to raster and flatten those elements to save in some of the formats: Illustrator is a tool much more suited to the task of grouped boxes, text and lines semantically linked.  
I often see people suggesting PS to edit text in a PDF and it drives me potty!!!